# Why does char allow registered sign?

Tags: sql-server

The data type of the column is `char` and I find it allows ® (registered sign).

Doesn't char only support ascii symbols? Isn't ® an unicode symbol? What other symbols are supported by char?

Comment: ® is ANSI character 174. See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa245259.aspx

Comment: @JonathanM: Char is not intended for UTF-8 and the multi-byte characters inherent in it.

Comment: Generally speaking, ASCII is not relevant to any modern system (after, say, 1981), except when you absolutely know it is.

Comment: @Blorgbeard Careful, in the ANSI code page [Windows-874](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-11) 174 is ฎ."ANSI" and "Extended ASCII" are not specific code pages, so the use of those term are quite limited, if not detrimental to understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Doesn't `char` only support ascii symbols?

Since `char` data type has 8 bits, and ASCII uses only 7 of them, SQL Server uses extended ASCII set for your selected [*code page*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186356(v=sql.105).aspx) when storing non-UNICODE character data.

> What other symbols are supported by char?

Run `sp_helpsort` to see what code page your server is using. When [code page 1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) is selected, your code set allows character ® to be encoded as 0xAE, or 174<sub>10</sub>. This number fits in a byte, so you can safely use it in a column of `char` data type.